# Failing to install Allure 2.13.8 on ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS manually

Tags: software-installation, format, curl

I have tried the following commands:

```
curl -o allure-2.13.8.tgz -Ls https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/generic/io/qameta/allure/allure/2.13.8/allure-2.13.8.tgz 
sudo tar -zxvf allure-2.13.8.tgz -C /opt/
```

But I am seeing the following problem:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I get 404 on this link.

Answer (score 3):

I was using the wrong url.

```
curl -o allure-2.13.8.tgz -OLs https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/qameta/allure/allure-commandline/2.13.8/allure-commandline-2.13.8.tgz
sudo tar -zxvf allure-2.13.8.tgz -C /opt/
sudo ln -s /opt/allure-2.13.8/bin/allure /usr/bin/allure
allure --version
```